# Start Thunderbird in Background

Tags: thunderbird, autostart

I have a lot of Mailfolders, this leads to thunderbird starting very slow.

I use the default Ubuntu desktop and it seems that all autostart applications need to be started until I can access the desktop.

How can I start thunderbird in .config/autostart, but in background

The desktop entry looks like this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=/usr/bin/thunderbird
Hidden=false
NoDisplay=false
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
Name[de]=/usr/bin/thunderbird
Name=/usr/bin/thunderbird
Comment[de]=
Comment=
```

I could not find something about starting in background in the [Desktop Entry Specifications](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html)

Has some a solution?

(BTW, I switched to a web based mail-user-agent in the year 2020. I think native GUIs are dead)

Comment: There's a ThB addon called MinimizeToTray. It may not work as you expect but it's worth a try.

Answer (score 1):

[FireTray](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/thunderbird/addon/firetray/) does what you need, and a lot more.

Answer (score 0):

If you have bash installed (which is the standard terminal shell in Ubuntu) you can use

```
...
Exec=bash -c "thunderbird &"
...
```

This should make the autostart process go on without waiting for thunderbird to finish loading.