# Missing system tray with Thunderbird after upgrading to 18.04

Tags: 18.04, thunderbird, system-tray

In 16.04 I used to have Thunderbird sit in the background and have an icon in the system tray. However in 18.04 the sys tray icon is gone, and as soon as I close Thunderbird it shuts down and I don't get any mail notifications.

Any way I can fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Have Thunderbird 52 running in background](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1049804/have-thunderbird-52-running-in-background). Extensions like Firetray which let Thunderbird stay minimised in the tray are not officially supported any more, you'll have to install manually.