# Thunderbird icon is missing in system tray bar in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, thunderbird, system-tray

In Ubuntu 16.04 I had a Thunderbird icon in tray bar with unread messages but there isn't in Ubuntu 18.04.

Is there a chance to have it again?

Comment: Try this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1049804/have-thunderbird-52-running-in-background

Comment: Thanks pomsky but in Ubuntu 16.04 I didn't use Firetray add-on

Comment: Thunderbird *itself* doesn't provide any option to show an icon in tray bar with unread messages, most probably it was a feature of Unity desktop environment that came with 16.04. Since Ubuntu 18.04 uses GNOME instead of Unity, you'll most probably have to try some alternative like Firetray.

Answer (score 1):

Try Birdtray (https://github.com/gyunaev/birdtray)

Install on Ubuntu 18.04:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linuxuprising/apps
$ sudo apt install birdtray
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the [desktop file from Mozilla](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mozilla/sumo-kb/main/installing-thunderbird-linux/thunderbird.desktop) I would suggest checking that file (typically in `/usr/local/share/applications`) to see if the `Icon=` property is pointing to the correct path.

In my case, I had installed Thunderbird to a different location than what is in that file by default and had to update the icon path to point to that location.