# Thunderbird 60.2.1 doesn't notify with new email?

Tags: 16.04, thunderbird

I want **thunderbird 60.2.1** to show email notifications even my **thunderbird** client is not active (*running in background*). It only works when I open the client. But It doesn't give notifications in background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open Thunderbird preferences. Then in the **General** tab check the '*Show an alert*' option under '*When new messages arrive*'.

Additionally, you can also check the '*Play a sound*' option for an audible alert.

Comment: It doesn't work. Instead it only works when I open (**make thunderbird client active**).

Comment: @RajeshK.Chaudhary Okay, *how* did you make Thunderbird run in background? Are you sure it's actually doing so? Old add-ons which used to make it possible stopped working with Thunderbird v60. Unless you have manually done something, Thunderbird will just close (instead of running in background) if you click the cross button or so.

Comment: Okay. So you mean to say, if I click close button in thunderbird, it doesn't run in background, rather it quits. I usually click `x` button after reading my emails.

Comment: @RajeshK.Chaudhary Exactly, on top of that most of extensions that used to make Thunderbird run in background became incompatible with v60+. See this for newer versions: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1084490/thunderbird-60-2-1-minimizetotray-revived-add-on-stopped-working